# web_app definition in two cookbooks, how do I only call one of them?

Tags: apache, nginx, chef-infra, chef-recipe

So we use chef for our servers and in the process of setting up munin, the munin cookbook now requires both nginx and apache2.

We also have our own recipes for setting up sites using the web_app definition.

If the server only has nginx or apache2 it works fine but as soon as both are required in the run list the web_app definition gets called in both apache2 and nginx this of course fails because you can't have two servers running on port 80.

Without modifying the cookbooks which is bad how can I get around this or scope to only apache  or nginx. Btw we need both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked through our commit logs and turns out its my own fault :-( I ported the web_app definition from apache over to port our own cookbooks from apache to nginx.... fail

EDIT: renamed web_app in the nginx recipe to nginx_app which solves the problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I answered my own question, I don't think having two definitions with the same name can be scoped, so that kind of is the answer.

Comment: this is the second time in 5 minutes I've seen people dinging someone for answering their own question.   If it's the right answer, it's the right answer, and you can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of confusion going on there... Only the [`apache2` cookbook](https://github.com/onehealth-cookbooks/apache2) has a [`web_app` definition](https://github.com/onehealth-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/definitions/web_app.rb). The [`nginx` cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx) uses a [`nginx_site` definition](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx/blob/master/definitions/nginx_site.rb).

That said, your issue seems to come from the fact that you have two different processes trying to listen on the same port on the same node. To fix that, you have to tell either `apache` or `nginx` to listen on a different port.

To configure `apache`, you have to override [`node[:apache][:listen_ports]`](https://github.com/onehealth-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/attributes/default.rb#L130) to exclude 80.

For `nginx`, you probably have to set your virtual hosts not to listen on port 80.

Comment: You are right but that isn't the issue, I don't want both of them running anyway.